# WP URL - Fix improper GET parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url, get

I discovered an issue where improper URL (GET) parameter causes 404 error.
Site is based on ***WordPress***

Example: *[www.somesite.com/page/&p=9&pos=9](http://www.somesite.com/page/&p=9&pos=9)*

Notice **&p=9&pos=9** at the end.

So instead of beginning the GET parameters with **?** it starts with **&**

This causes site to display 404 Error page instead of showing correct page, while ignoring the parameters.

How do I fix this programmatically (.htaccess or PHP or some other way), so this issue does not occur again?

Thanks all

Comment: You need to find the code that's adding the `&p=9&pos=9` and make sure they are being added correctly as querystring paramters

Comment: Check the template where this pagination is created, it is most likely calling `paginate_links`, or any of the functions that are based on it and take the same parameters. The `format` argument of that specifies how exactly the parameter gets inserted into the URL, that might simply be specified in a wrong way there. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/